# imapd-ssl: admin: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, postfix, pam, courier, saslauthd

I am trying to set up my VPS so I can use Thunderbird IMAP to manage my mails. First, I installed `postfix` and followed [this](http://www.e-rave.nl/create-a-self-signed-ssl-key-for-postfix) guide to create an SSL certificate. Then I installed `sasl2-bin` and `courier-imap-ssl` and found [this (German) guide](http://www.huschi.net/4_111_de-debian-postfix-smtp-auth-einrichten.html) to set up SASL. Even though it is German, you might still be able to see what I've done from the commands shown.

After Courier was installed, Thunderbird finally accepted my configuration and asked me if I would trust the certificate, which I accepted. * However, it is unable to log in. Looking at `/var/log/mail.info`, whenever Thunderbird attempts to authenticate, it logs what you can find below, "admin" being my user name.

```
Nov 19 22:55:19 vps imapd-ssl: chdir Maildir: No such file or directory
Nov 19 22:55:19 vps imapd-ssl: admin: No such file or directory
```

However, I can verify that the PAM authentication works.

```
admin@vps:~$ sudo testsaslauthd -f /var/run/saslauthd/mux -u admin -p 'mypassword'
0: OK "Success."
```

Any clues are highly appreciated.

---

** Courier has created its own certificate, so I'm not even sure if my manually generated one is actually in use somewhere. It is still configured to be used in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` though.*

**Edit**: I accidentally confused Cyrus with Courier. I have actually installed courier. Per @masegaloeh 's request, you can find the configurations below.

`postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.niklasrosenstein.com niklasrosenstein.com
myhostname = mail.niklasrosenstein.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.niklasrosenstein.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.niklasrosenstein.com.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

`/etc/courier/authdaemonrc`

```
##VERSION: $Id: authdaemonrc.in,v 1.13 2005/10/05 00:07:32 mrsam Exp $
#
# Copyright 2000-2005 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for
# distribution information.
#
# authdaemonrc created from authdaemonrc.dist by sysconftool
#
# Do not alter lines that begin with ##, they are used when upgrading
# this configuration.
#
# This file configures authdaemond, the resident authentication daemon.
#
# Comments in this file are ignored.  Although this file is intended to
# be sourced as a shell script, authdaemond parses it manually, so
# the acceptable syntax is a bit limited.  Multiline variable contents,
# with the \ continuation character, are not allowed.  Everything must
# fit on one line.  Do not use any additional whitespace for indentation,
# or anything else.

##NAME: authmodulelist:2
#
# The authentication modules that are linked into authdaemond.  The
# default list is installed.  You may selectively disable modules simply
# by removing them from the following list.  The available modules you
# can use are: authuserdb authpam authpgsql authldap authmysql authcustom authpipe

authmodulelist="authpam"

##NAME: authmodulelistorig:3
#
# This setting is used by Courier's webadmin module, and should be left
# alone

authmodulelistorig="authuserdb authpam authpgsql authldap authmysql authcustom authpipe"

##NAME: daemons:0
#
# The number of daemon processes that are started.  authdaemon is typically
# installed where authentication modules are relatively expensive: such
# as authldap, or authmysql, so it's better to have a number of them running.
# PLEASE NOTE:  Some platforms may experience a problem if there's more than
# one daemon.  Specifically, SystemV derived platforms that use TLI with
# socket emulation.  I'm suspicious of TLI's ability to handle multiple
# processes accepting connections on the same filesystem domain socket.
#
# You may need to increase daemons if as your system load increases.  Symptoms
# include sporadic authentication failures.  If you start getting
# authentication failures, increase daemons.  However, the default of 5
# SHOULD be sufficient.  Bumping up daemon count is only a short-term
# solution.  The permanent solution is to add more resources: RAM, faster
# disks, faster CPUs...

daemons=5

##NAME: authdaemonvar:2
#
# authdaemonvar is here, but is not used directly by authdaemond.  It's
# used by various configuration and build scripts, so don't touch it!

authdaemonvar=/var/run/courier/authdaemon

##NAME: DEBUG_LOGIN:0
#
# Dump additional diagnostics to syslog
#
# DEBUG_LOGIN=0   - turn off debugging
# DEBUG_LOGIN=1   - turn on debugging
# DEBUG_LOGIN=2   - turn on debugging + log passwords too
#
# ** YES ** - DEBUG_LOGIN=2 places passwords into syslog.
#
# Note that most information is sent to syslog at level 'debug', so
# you may need to modify your /etc/syslog.conf to be able to see it.

DEBUG_LOGIN=0

##NAME: DEFAULTOPTIONS:0
#
# A comma-separated list of option=value pairs. Each option is applied
# to an account if the account does not have its own specific value for
# that option. So for example, you can set
#   DEFAULTOPTIONS="disablewebmail=1,disableimap=1"
# and then enable webmail and/or imap on individual accounts by setting
# disablewebmail=0 and/or disableimap=0 on the account.

DEFAULTOPTIONS=""

##NAME: LOGGEROPTS:0
#
# courierlogger(1) options, e.g. to set syslog facility
#

LOGGEROPTS=""

##NAME: LDAP_TLS_OPTIONS:0
#
# Options documented in ldap.conf(5) can be set here, prefixed with 'LDAP'.
# Examples:
#
#LDAPTLS_CACERT=/path/to/cacert.pem
#LDAPTLS_REQCERT=demand
#LDAPTLS_CERT=/path/to/clientcert.pem
#LDAPTLS_KEY=/path/to/clientkey.pem
```

Comment: @masegaloeh I have added the Courier configuration and `postfix -n` output. I have accidentally confused Cyrus with Courier (by name). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have mismatch between where postfix stores the emails and where courier search the emails.

- Looking on your postfix configuration, it pretty clear that you let postfix store the email in default format and default places, **`/var/spool/mail/$user` with mbox format**.
- In courier, you use **authpam** as authentication module. So it's expected that courier will search the emails from **`/home/$user/Maildir` with maildir format**.

---

The easy fix is change the location and format when postfix store emails. To do that, add this parameter in `main.cf`

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

It will change postfix behavior to stores email in ~/Maildir/ with maildir format.

Comment: That is correct, also send a message to yourself so that the folder will be created because if it does not exist it you will still receive the error